# Source of Baruch SheAmar melody

Tags: tefilla, music

In my old shul, we used to sing a version of baruch she'amar that, to my understanding, was a fairly standard, traditional version. however, I've tried to find it recently and can't. I've transcribed the first few lines as I remember them and shared the melody [here](https://www76.zippyshare.com/v/zeJmjV0M/file.html); also an image version follows:

[image]

Can anyone tell who arranged this version, or at least point me to a complete recording of it?

EDIT : Now there is an mp3 of how this sounds (to the best of my recollection...), link in the comments below.

Comment: Welcome to MY! You may make our job easier if you could add details about the _nusach_ of your old synagogue.

Comment: @kazi : ashkenazi polen nusach. also, yes!, now that you mention it, it would be -- unfortunately i didn't think of that... :(

Comment: hmm... strangely, it seem that some of the comments got deleted, including my [link](https://www76.zippyshare.com/v/zeJmjV0M/file.html) to the mp3.

Comment: Unused comments get deleted, and I edited in your link.